# phpinfo() showing invalid value

Tags: nginx, webserver, php

test.php

```
<?php
sleep(45);
phpinfo();
```

upon executing above code, 
after **47 sec**, i'm getting response :

> max_execution_time 30 | 30

strange but yes `phpinfo()` showing invalid timeout value.

upon `sleep(75);phpinfo();` after **61 sec** I'm getting request timout error in browser.

**Problem:** Not sure why `phpinfo()` is showing invalid value?

```
PHP Version: 5.6.29
Server API: FPM/FastCGI
php-fpm:    active
NGINX_VERSION:  1.11.8; linux
```

from above tests, it seems, server max_execution_time is 60 sec but its showing 30sec in phpinfo();

Answer (score 1):

No, this is entirely expected. sleep() is *blocking* call. PHP doesn't know it has timed out until the execution thread is scheduled by the OS.

Try:

```
for ($x=0; $x<30; $x++) sleep(2);
```

Comment: `for ($x=0; $x<30; $x++) sleep(2); phpinfo();` resulted in '504-request time out'
`for ($x=0; $x<27; $x++) sleep(2);phpinfo();` resulted with phpinfo() response: 'max_execution_time=30|30'
*conclusion* : script took 56.13sec to respond & phpinfo() saying max_execution_time per script is 30.

Comment: I must confess: I wasn't expecting that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(300)
sleep(45);
phpinfo();
```

set new max_execution_time with set_time_limit() function

Comment: You should read the question again. It isn't about how to set the time limit.